# Android Studio Build.VERSION_CODES.R and Window.getInsetsController() is Missing

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I was following a course on udemy where the instructor asks to use the following code.
[image: An image showing the code that the instructor required]

I tried using the same code but encountered multiple errors.
Here is what android studio looks like when I type in the same code.

[image: My code]

First, android studio cannot recognize the symbol
`Build.VERSION_CODES.R`

When I hover over the highlighted text in android studio it gives me the following message:

> Uncessary; SDK_INT is never < 21

This makes no sense as first of all `Build.VERSION_CODES.R` is api level 30 and my minimum targeted api is level 21. Secondly even if my `SDK_INT` can't go below 21. the version codes inside of `Build.VERSION_CODES` shouldn't change.

The next error that android studio shows is that it can't resolve `window.insetsController`

> Unresolved reference: insetsController

If I browse the source code for the `Window` class inside of android studio I can see the `getInsetsController` method that the `insetsController` field is supposed to wrap. I tried using the method directly instead of the kotlin getter and android studio can't recognize the method either.

[image: Android studio showing that Window.getInsetsController() cannot be found]

Another field that android studio can't find is `WindowInsets.Type`, I can see that it exists inside the source code, but I can't access it.

My `compileSdkVersion` is set to `29` and `buildToolsVersion` is set to `"29.0.3"`.

If anyone has any idea of what is going on, it would be greatly appreciated if you could answer. I've tried creating a new project and trying the same code but the errors persist. Maybe the sdk that I'm using is broken? But my sdk is the one that comes with android studio so I'm not sure. Recently, I updated android studio from 4.0 to 4.1, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My compileSdkVersion is set to 29

Set it to `30`. Android R (Android 11) is API Level 30.

Always set your `compileSdkVersion` to the latest production version of Android.

Comment: Should I also change my `buildToolsVersion` to `"30.0.0"`?

Comment: @KamS: You could remove that line -- Android Studio will use an appropriate build tools version by default.

Comment: @CommonsWare , my compileSdkVersion is 30 and I still get unresolved symbol R in Build.VERSION_CODES.R